JoinHandle: cannot move out of `*handler` which is behind a shared reference
I am trying to make a rust app that can create, start & stop multiple simple REST servers.
For this, I use rouille.
I store the serverInstances using a hashMap behind a lazyLock:
use rouille::{Response, Server};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Mutex, LazyLock, mpsc::Sender};
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

struct ServerInstance {
    // ...
    stop: (JoinHandle<()>, Sender<()>),
}

static SERVER_INSTANCES: LazyLock<Mutex<HashMap<usize, ServerInstance>>> =
    LazyLock::new(|| Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

async fn start_server(id: usize, port: i16) {
    let server = Server::new(format!("0.0.0.0:{}", port), |request| {
        Response::text("hello world")
    })
    .unwrap();
    SERVER_INSTANCES.lock().unwrap().insert(
        id,
        ServerInstance { /* ..., */ stop: server.stoppable() },
    );
}

However, when I try to stop the server using this function:
fn stop_server_command(id: usize) {
    if let Some(instance) = SERVER_INSTANCES.lock().unwrap().get(&id) {
        let (handler, signal) = &instance.stop;
        signal.send(()).unwrap();
        handler.join().unwrap();
//      ^^^^^^^ ------ `*handler` moved due to this method call
    }
}

I get this error on handler.join():
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*handler` which is behind a shared reference
    --> src\lib.rs:47:9
     |
47   |         handler.join().unwrap();
     |         ^^^^^^^ ------ `*handler` moved due to this method call
     |         |
     |         move occurs because `*handler` has type `std::thread::JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
     |
note: `std::thread::JoinHandle::<T>::join` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `*handler`

Any ideas on how I should handle this?

Can you use .remove instead of .get? To call .join you need to give up ownership of the JoinHandle.

If remove is no option, you could wrap the handle in an Option and take it.

As was mentioned in comment by @loganfsmyth, in order to call join on JoinHanlde you need to own it (because join "consumes" the JoinHandle). But get method on HashMap provides you with a borrow, not an ownership. So the solution would be to use remove to obtain owned value from HashMap
fn stop_server_command(id: usize) {
    if let Some((handler, signal)) = SERVER_INSTANCES.lock().unwrap().remove(&id) {
        signal.send(()).unwrap();
        handler.join().unwrap();
    }
}


Thank you & @loganfsmyth
I'm new to Rust (obviously) - this makes sense!
